# Decimal numbers are being rounded off after performing arithmetic operations

Tags: abap

I'm trying to make a simple ABAP program that exercises various arithmetic operations.

The first number is: 5

The second number is 3

Answers should be:

SUM: 8

DIFFERENCE: 2

PRODUCT: 15

QUOTIENT: 1.67

MODULO: 2

I tried declaring the quotient variable into Packed Number and include 2 decimal places but I'm getting different results.

Here's my code:

```
*Parameter declaration - Display fields
PARAMETERS: p_no1 TYPE p DEFAULT 5,
            p_no2 TYPE p DEFAULT 3.

*Data Declaration
DATA(gv_sum) = ( p_no1 + p_no2 ).
DATA(gv_diff) = ( p_no1 - p_no2 ).
DATA(gv_prod) = ( p_no1 * p_no2 ).
DATA: gv_quo TYPE p DECIMALS 2,
      gv_mod TYPE p DECIMALS 2.

gv_quo = ( p_no1 DIV p_no2 ).
gv_mod = ( p_no1 MOD p_no2 ).

*Output
WRITE: 'First Number is:', p_no1,
     / 'Second Number is:', p_no2,
     / 'The Sum is:', gv_sum,
     / 'The Difference is:', gv_diff,
     / 'The Product is:', gv_prod,
     / 'The Quotient is:', gv_quo,
     / 'The Modulo is:', gv_mod.
```

The result I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: It seems, you have an *integer division*: `5 / 3 == 1`. Try using floating point arithmetics: `gv_quo = ( (p_no1 + 0.0) / p_no2 ).`

Comment: `DIV` means integer division. You need to use the classic arithmetic division `/`. See ABAP documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

DIV gives you the rounded result of your division.
If you wants the decimal part go for '/' instead of DIV.
MOD gives you remainder of your division.

Best regards
Sebastian